# click and mouse event conflict in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

recently,i try to write a todo demo via vuejs,however,when i write the following code

```
<div id="item_lists">
                <div class='user_choice_item' v-for="todo in todos" @mouseenter="showDeleteBtn($index,$event)" v-on:mouseleave.self="hideDeleteBtn($index,$event)">
                    <input type='checkbox' name='item_cbx' v-model="todo.checked" />
                    <label class='with_cbx_item'>{{todo.content}}</label>
                    <span class='delete_bt'  v-on:click.stop="deleteTodo(todo)" v-show="todo.show"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

//js

```
var todoList = new Vue({
    el:"#item_lists",
    data:{
        todos:[]
    },
    methods:{
        showDeleteBtn:function(index,event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(event.currentTarget.className!=="user_choice_item")
                return;

            var newState = Object.assign({},this.todos[index],{show:true});
            this.todos.$set(index,newState);
        },
        hideDeleteBtn:function(index,event){
            var newState = Object.assign({},this.todos[index],{show:false});
            this.todos.$set(index,newState);
        },
        deleteTodo:function(todo){

            this.todos.$remove(todo);
            return false;
        },


    }
});
```

it turns out that the only the mouseenter event can be triggered correctly, the click on "delete_btn" and change event on the checkbox ,the mouseleave event not triggered. however, when i remove the mouseenter event of the parent div. the child events work .i wanna know what causes this ..can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be working too hard at handling the event. Here's a snippet that does what I think you want it to do. The `showDeleteBtn` and `hideDeleteBtn` methods simply set the `show` data member of the `todo` item.

```js
var todoList = new Vue({
  el: "#item_lists",
  data: {
    todos: [{
      content: 'Hi there',
      checked: true,
      show: false
    },
    {
      content: 'Another',
      checked: true,
      show: false
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    showDeleteBtn: function(index) {
      this.todos[index].show = true;
    },
    hideDeleteBtn: function(index) {
      this.todos[index].show = false;
    },
    deleteTodo: function(todo) {
      this.todos.$remove(todo);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.delete_bt {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="item_lists">
  <div class='user_choice_item' v-for="todo in todos" v-on:mouseenter="showDeleteBtn($index)" v-on:mouseleave="hideDeleteBtn($index)">
    <input type='checkbox' name='item_cbx' v-model="todo.checked" />
    <label class='with_cbx_item'>{{todo.content}}</label>
    <span class='delete_bt' v-on:click.stop="deleteTodo(todo)" v-show="todo.show">Delete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes! i made it yesterday, and i found that it still works just by set the attr rather than the whole obj. however, i wanna know is there any method that can help me change some(more than one)attributes at a time?

Comment: You can change as many attributes as you want. They just need to be part of your viewmodel.